# 'Expect' function with wait parameter in WebdriverIO does not work

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io

I'm new to webdriverio, currently ran into a problem. I need to implement something like awaitility in Java - to make expect() function try for successfull assertion for some time with poll interval before failing. I already tried https://webdriver.io/docs/api/expect-webdriverio.html, so i set up

```
    beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
    require('expect-webdriverio').setOptions({ wait: 50000 })
},
```

in my wdio.conf.ts, but it's not working for me. It seems it does not wait for timeout, just fails right after my expect() is called. Can you please advice me what could i possibly do wrong?

UPDATE:
my expect:

```
it('should be able to save stuff', () => {
    expect(mainPage.getDataForRow('My row', 'My row')).toBe('Hello');
});
```

Comment: it should work, but not for all assertions. Could you provide an example where it is not working for you? I'll try to explain why

Comment: @Andrei it's just some simple expect which uses .toBe('some string') matcher. I added details in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is working for built in matchers. For example `expect(elem).toHaveElementProperty('height', 23)` or `expect(myInput).toHaveAttributeContaining('class', 'form')`. These higher order matchers already contain "polling" logic inside of them. However in your code example you take the value of the element at exact moment of executing this line with `mainPage.getDataForRow('My row', 'My row')` and trying to compare it with `'Hello'`. The right way is to use correct matchers that are provided out of the box, rather than "get" methods. But if your situation is veeery specific you can try to implement helper with polling behavior yourself. example:

```
function expectToContainText(elem, text) {
  return borser.wait(() => element.getAttribute('innerText').then(innerText => innerText == text));
}
```

Comment: Thank you really much, helped me a lot! Works fine now once i changed the expect logic. Thanks and have a nice New Year celebration!